# Overriding hashCode when using HashMap, HashSet etc?

Tags: java, hashcode

The question is in the title. I use `HashMap` as follows:

```
Map<Player, Partner> m = new HashMap<Player, Partner>();
//do some on m
```

Where both `Player` and `Partner` are just a `POJO` representing data-model.

```
public class Player{

    private int id;

    private String name;
    //etc, GET, SET
}

public class Partner{

    private int id;

    private String name;
    //etc, GET, SET
}
```

I would like to say that two objects of those classes are equivalent ***iff*** they have the same `id`. So, should I write `hashCode` something like

```
public int hashCode(){
    return id;
}
```

Is that a correct way to do that and why should I use it ever when I'm going to use HashMap or something similar?

Comment: if you are talking about equivalence you should be overriding equals

Comment: @Leon Not exactly, I don't understand why I should ever override shashCode when I use HashMap

Comment: For you DTOs you should always override hashcode, equals and toString

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Such `hashCode` would work. You'll also have to override `equals` in a consistent manner:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other)
{
    if (!(other instanceof Player))
        return false;
    Player op = (Player) other;
    return id == op.id;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've read about overriding both hashCode and equals method. But I don't udnerstand why I should do that. For instance, why do I have to override equals whenever I use HashMap? And what happens If I override equals and don't override hashCode?

Comment: @St.Antario Both hashCode and equals are used to locate a key in a HashMap. Two different keys may have the same hashCode (and even if they don't, they may be mapped to the same bucket in the HashMap, since the number of buckets is much smaller than the number of possible hash codes), so equals is used to determine if they are actaully equal.

Comment: @St.Antario If you override equals and not hashCode, the default implementation of hashCode will be used. So two Players having the same id (which you consider to be equal), may have a different hashCode, so they might be placed in different buckets in the HashMap, which means containsKey may return false incorrectly and you may be able to put the same key twice in the Map.

Comment: @St.Antario the correct implementation of `equals` and `hashCode` is a topic for a book. The usage of these methods to implement the Java Collections API is another book. You should read up on this independently.

Answer (score 1):

The objects are stored in hash buckets,Say if you have 100 objects, If 50 out of the 100 return hashcode value "123" and remaining 50 returns "124" they are stored in differet two buckets and hence reduces search time required.

While searching first aim is to find bucket in which the object belongs to, once finds the bucket then calls equls method to find the object

Rather than stroing all objects in one place (searching is difficult), hash based collections groups together objects having same hash code value, each such group is stored in a place called as hash bucket